# Ambiguous reference to member '..<' - Swift 4

Tags: swift4, xcode9

I am using the String+Extensions pod and I am trying to migrate my project to Xcode 9 + Swift 4 and the function below starts to give the error **Ambiguous reference to member '..<'** .

```
func times(_ n: Int) -> String {
    return (0..<n).reduce("") { $0.0 + self }
}
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Not everyone knows what the String+Extensions pod is.

Answer (score 1):

Please check :

```
func times(_ n: Int) -> String {
    return (0..<n).reduce("") { (str1, str2) in str1 + self }
}
```